# TextBox not containing "\r\n" strings

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a program which needs to determine the number of lines in a multiline textbox to know how to process it.  I am calling the TextBox.Lines.Length property, which was working.  Now however, no matter how many lines of text are visible in the GUI, this value is 1, and all of the "\r\n" strings have disappeared from the TextBox.Text string.  Any Ideas? My code is as following :

```
TextBox.MultiLine = true;
TextBox.WordWrap = true;
for (int i = 0; i < TextBox.Lines.Length - 1; i++)
    //Some Code
```

Comment: There is no way anyone will be able to diagnose this issue without further details, including seeing what code you have at the very least.

Comment: Web or winforms? Post some code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: anything to do with `WordWrap` (WinForm) or `TextWrapping` (WPF)?

Comment: Just a wild guess: try `myTextbox.Multiline = true;`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff.aspx

Comment: It is a winforms app.  What part of the code would be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment, with `Multiline=True` and `WordWrap=True`, your textbox will display a long line as multilines (Wrapped)... but actually it is one single line, and that's why your `Lines.Length=1`, try type in some line break yourself, and test it again. Or you can set `WordWrap=False`, and you will see there is only one line...

Comment: I suppose that is another question? I'm leaving now, but you can check something like the character width, and insert line break, when it's reaching the limit (e.g. your textbox's width)

Answer (score 0):

It will need to be marked as multiline, check that, you can parse like so:

```
string txt = TextBox1.Text;
string[] lst = txt.Split(new Char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: I would imagine it wouldn't work, because that doesn't even make sense. Use the code I posted above? If you can't see how that fits into your own code, then provide a code example so we can help.